# Rails, how to submit disabled checkbox with true when checked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble working with disabled checkboxes.

I've tried two approaches. 
first:

```
= check_box "permissions", "permission_#{row}[create]", {checked: has_permission?(@user, permission, "create")}, 'true', 'false'
```

This checkbox is disabled inside of the view but also checked, but when submitted it's value in my params looks like this:

```
"create"=>"false"
```

So when I update my attributes, created is changed from true to false in my params.

How can I send true to my params instead of false, when a disabled checkbox is checked?

Comment: Try the first one with the `disabled` flag set to true so like this: `<%= check_box "permissions", "permission_#{row}[create]", {checked: has_permission?(@user, permission, "create")}, 'true', 'false', disabled: true %>`. That might keep it out of your params. No guarantees though

Comment: A check box not in your params should be treated as false. Only treat it as true if it is checked.

Comment: When a html form field is disabled it will not be returned to the server, so it would only send back the value for the hidden field(which would be false) If you wanted to return `true` for a disabled field you would either need to update the hidden field, or have your own hidden field to send you back the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the reason why you've disabled those checkboxes in the first place is to make permissions read-only. But it's very easy for someone to remove the `disabled` flag from the checkbox by using browser debugging tools, set the permissions and submit.

Therefore I would suggest removing these values from `params` before handing to the model no matter what, for example by excluding them from the allowed parameters, or by issuing `splice`.

This way you will still be displaying the actual permissions, but ignoring any attempt to change them without authorization.

Comment: In that case when I use this line instead: `%input{:name => "permissions[permission_#{row}][grant]", :type => "CHECKBOX", checked: has_permission?(@user, permission, "grant")}` My disabled paramaters don't get sent into my params.  Which is great! but it does not send a unchecked checkbox value, which is needed if a user is removing a permission.

Comment: Whether they're sent or not doesn't really make much difference. Malicious user can craft any request, so you'd better be ready for it on the server side.

As for the unchecked value not being sent, one solution that comes to mind in pseudocode is something like: `if user_has_permission_to_change?('permission_0[create]'); model.permitted = params['permission_0[create]']; end` (sorry, no fancy formatting in the comments).

This will prevent users that don't have the permission from updating the value, yet make the checkboxes work for the ones that do have the permission to change permissions.